# How to remove a word when page load?

Tags: jquery

My goal here is to remove the specified word inside a div tag when the page load.
Heres my code.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(function() {
    var text = jQuery('#breadcrumbs').text();
    var wordsCount = text.split(' ').length;
      new_str3= text.split(' ');
      var dd = new_str3.length;
      new_str3.splice(-2, 1, ' ');
 //i add this #output_ for me to see the output
jQuery('#output_').html(new_str3.join(''));
      });
  });
```

This is the unmodified before the output.

> Home » Procedures » Sample Procedures » Breast » **Augmentation**

Now the output of my code is this.

> Home»Procedures»SampleProcedures»Breast Augmentation

If you notice theres no **"»"** between the Breast and Augmentation. Now, what i want is, when the page load, the character **"»"** between Breast & Augmentation inside the **#breadcrumbs** would be remove automatically so that the output now would be:

> Home » Procedures » Sample Procedures » **Breast Augmentation**

Pls help me how to do it just by enhancing my given code. And pls. dont ask me why i am doing this because of it is breadcrumbs, this is for a purpose.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to split by » and concatenate the last two pieces?

Comment: @t0mppa could you show me how to do it? Im thinking also of that way, getting those last two words only and modify them in order not to change the other linked words.

Comment: There are a couple answers already, trying to do that. If you want a more thorough answer with all the HTML fixed up with links and bolded text working properly, would help if you'd post the HTML structure in your breadcrumbs to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this using `lastIndexOf` and `slice`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('#breadcrumbs').text(function(i, v) {
        var index = v.lastIndexOf("»");
        return v.slice(0, index) + v.slice(index + 2);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pranavcbalan/kTS5r/1/)

Comment: Well, obviously the OP wants a more general approach, as you can see from how he handles the words.

Comment: I think thats replacing totally the div tag, in short plain text. Note also that "Home » Procedures » Sample Procedures" are links and should be links. And by the way, its a dynamic page.

Answer (score -1):

so - you need to remove always last symbol ">>" - right?
why don't you split with ">>" and then concatenate whole string once again but without ">>" before last element in array
this should be something like this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  jQuery(function() {
    var text = jQuery('#breadcrumbs').text();
    var textArray = text.split('>>');
var breadcrumbs = '';
for(i = 0; i< textArray.length -2; i++) //without 2 last elements
{
breadcrumbs += textArray[i];
breadcrumbs += " >> ";
}
//and now two last elements
breadcrumbs += textArray[textArray.length -1];
breadcrumbs += textArray[textArray.length];
jQuery('#output_').html(breadcrumbs);
      });
  });
```

it should work (but not tested ;p)